# Multi-Session Manager for Git Bash Like GNU's Screen

Tags: git, cygwin, tmux, gnu-screen, byobu

I'm not sure what to name this question, as I am not sure what the technical name is for the type of program I am talking about.

Is there a program available for `Git Bash` that is similar to `screen`, `tmux`, or `byobu`? I know all 3 are available for `Cygwin`, but I can not find information about using them with `Git Bash`. I like `Git Bash` because it is simpler and takes up less space, among other things.

Comment: possibly related http://superuser.com/questions/268042/terminal-emulator-with-split-panes-for-windows-7-64-bit

Comment: Wow @user2485710, that looks as good as or better than `screen`/the others! But I'd guess it's for a different purpose & takes up more space. I'll have to research it some more.

Comment: For some reason `StackOverflow` isn't letting me tag this question as `git-bash` and keeps changing it to `git`.

Comment: @trysis, [tag:git-bash] [is a synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) for [tag:git].

Comment: Oh... now I feel stupid.

Comment: The OP (and myself) are looking for something that allows one to attach and detach from sessions, not have a bunch of windows open simultaneously.

Comment: Maybe http://superuser.com/questions/701141/how-to-add-more-commands-to-git-bash-shell helps here?

Answer (score 10):

Nowadays the official git for windows is based at msys2 which seems to have tmux package at least. You can install g4w sdk as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712133) and then install tmux through pacman.

Comment: I am facing a challenge in installing tmux plugins.
and I get this weird error called server lost. I basically for now want my sessions to persist between system restarts. I want to achieve that using tpm, resurrect and continuum for a start. Please suggest some pointers for installing tmux plugins while using g4w sdk.

Comment: Doesn't work for me even though I've installed the latest Git 64-bit.
For `tmux` I get `tmux which: no tmux in` then a bunch of directories listed. And the `pacman` command is not found.