# Installing packages in Git-Bash

Tags: git-bash

In Git-Bash,I am trying to install urw-fonts.

This can be done by

`yum install urw-fonts`

but I did this and I got

`bash: yum: command not found`

i tried apt-get install urw-fonts and i got

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package urw-fonts`

please help me with this.

Comment: does anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Package management in git for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712133/package-management-in-git-for-windows)

Comment: We have to run apt-get update initially to install packages. Worked for me.