# Can I configure git for windows to work with a separate and full mingw64 install to have both packman and windows Git-Bash?

Tags: windows, git, git-bash, mingw-w64

This is a follow up to this 2018 SO question: [Package management in git for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712133/package-management-in-git-for-windows)

The answer to above question suggests to install GIT SDK. That is a big installation.

Fast forward to mid 2020 I hope I can find a more efficient approach.

Can I install a **full** mingw64 in a separate folder, so I have `packman` and `update-core`, then config the git installation at `C:\Program Files\Git\` to point to full installtion of mingw64 at `c:\mingw64` ?

Alternatively can I manually xcopy packman binaries to `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64` folder if that is an easier approach to add `packman` and `update-core` to the limited mingw64 that comes with Git for Windows?